# reference of that

Tags: reference

I am reading *Out of my Mind* by Sharon Draper.

I have questions about the last sentence in Chapter 11.

(For your information, Rose is a normal kid and "I" am a physically challenged kid. They became friends after "I" joined the inclusion class)

> Rose tells me secrets sometimes. I know she bites her fingernails, and she hates milk. She goes to church every Sunday but falls asleep until it's over. Me too. She has a younger sister just like I do. She even likes country music. Sometimes she tells me about trips to the mall with her friends.
>
> It would be so tight to be able to do **that**.

I was wondering what **that** in the last sentence refers to (trips to the mall) or talking about the trips to the mall?) or what the whole sentence means.

Comment: It's about the trips, not about talking about the trips.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: I think the book's usage is somewhat poor English, but I interpret as referring to *[taking] trips to the mall with friends.* *Do* refers to a previously stated action, and that seems to be the action being referenced.